# Using npm to install Ionic Cloud but get error about Jasmine

Tags: npm, jasmine, angularfire

I am running this command to add Ionic Cloud to my project:

```
npm install --save @ionic/cloud-angular
```

But I get this error:

```
npm WARN angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @types/jasmine@^2.5.36 but none was installed.
```

What do i need to do to get Jasmine installed? I assume this is what I need to do.

I have tried:

```
npm install --save jasmine
```

But this gives me:

```
npm install --save jasmine
ionic-hello-world@ /Users/chris/Documents/ionic/wurk
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @types/jasmine@^2.5.36
└── jasmine@2.5.2 

npm WARN angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @types/jasmine@^2.5.36 but none was installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install @types/jasmine

```
npm install @types/jasmine --save
```

see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jasmine